# StoredProcedure in C#, passing parameters from text boxes

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have very simple page just wan to find out how to pass data from text boxes into my procedure. I am kind of new with passing parameters from code behind in to DB,I have one page  for that code is

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:TextBox ID="LastName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="FirstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="Phone1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="Phone2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
        <br />
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TicketsConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Employee]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and aspx code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TicketsConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("InsertIntoEmployee", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = LastName.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Phone1", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Phone2", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    cmd.Parameters["@LastName"].Value = LastName.Text;
    cmd.Parameters["@FirstName"].Value = FirstName.Text;
    cmd.Parameters["@Phone1"].Value = Phone1.Text;
    cmd.Parameters["@Phone2"].Value = Phone2.Text;
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    }
}
```

web.config looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="TicketsConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=&quot;C:\Users\Asya\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\WebSites\WebSite6\App_Code\Tickets.mdf&quot;;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

When i pass simple data in to my prosedure it throws error

```
An SqlParameter with ParameterName '@LastName' is not contained by this SqlParameterCollection.
```

How to resolve this problem? Because on DB  side procedure works perfectly
 As I saed before I am really  new in to it. and I fixed previous problems but  here another one

```
The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.FormatException: The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0.

Source Error: 


Line 34:         cmd.Parameters["@Phone2"].Value = Phone2.Text;
Line 35:         con.Open();
Line 36:         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
Line 37:         con.Close();
Line 38:
```

Procedure which i use

```
procedure InsertIntoEmployee
@LastName Nvarchar (25) ,
@FirstName Nvarchar (25) , 
@Phone1 Nvarchar (25) ,
@Phone2 Nvarchar (25)
as 
insert into  Employee  (LastName , FirstName,Phone1,Phone2)values (@LastName,@FirstName,@Phone1,@Phone2);
```

when i run prosedure on Db side like 
`EXEC InsertIntoEmployee N'петров', N'петр', 99999999,null`
it works perfectly but from asp.net side its throwing errors

Comment: Show us the SQL procedure header, please. Just the part with the parameter specification.

Comment: It seems like you keep fixing things and then changing the question with more issues. If you want help, you probably should keep it on point and approve of the correct answer and then move onto other unrelated items. In addition, many of the variables you are using implement IDisposable and should be disposed of. Check out better examples online of how to do a SQL query (i.e. use using { var con = new SQLConnection...).

Comment: The my problem was how to pass parameters into Procedure on ASP.Net side and errors related to it. on DB  side it is really easy for me but asp.net  side confusing me all the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("InsertIntoEmployee", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;            
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.NVarChar(MAX)).Value = LastName.Text;
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.NVarChar(MAX)).Value = FirstName.Text;
          cmd.Parameters.Add("@Phone1", SqlDbType.NVarChar(MAX)).Value = Phone1.Text;
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@Phone2", SqlDbType.NVarChar(MAX)).Value = Phone2.Text;
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

      //  gvQuarterlyReport.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: `The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0.` Line 36:         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: I did not see the date column in your code ? where is that ? the first name and lastname is date time field ?

Comment: No all of the fields is Nvarchar.

Comment: Also if I am trying to use your way it  showing thios error Error `Non-invocable member 'System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar' cannot be used like a method.` doesnt like this part `NVarChar(MAX)`

Answer (score 3):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems that this line

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName ", SqlDbType.Date);
```

Have an extra space after *LastName*. Should it be

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.Date);
```

Instead?

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the space from "@LastName "

Something like

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.Date);
```

But that will just transfer the error to the nest line as `@FirstName` is also not in the parameter list.

In fact, after you have correct @LastName

all 3 these line will cause problems

```
cmd.Parameters["@FirstName"].Value = FirstName.Text;
cmd.Parameters["@Phone1"].Value = Phone1.Text;
cmd.Parameters["@Phone2"].Value = Phone2.Text
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answers about the space are correct, of course. Note that you can avoid such issues (or at least have them consistently wrong ;-) if you assign the parameters values right away, like so:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = LastName.Text;
```

Furthermore you used `SqlDbType.Date` for your `@LastName` parameter. Unless you have a very weird schema, that is most likely wrong. Hence, I used `SqlDbType.VarChar` above.